# Phones can't connect to local server

Tags: iphone, server, web-applications, vite, localserver

I'm trying to get my phone to connect to a local server from my PC to test a web app using Vite.

I've got my PC's IPv4 address and the right port number together and I can connect to it from my laptop and Android tablet, but not my iPhone or Android phone. I've tested using my laptop and everything can connect to that. My PC is using a USB Wi-Fi adapter so I've tried plugging it into my laptop and disabling the built in Wi-Fi adapter, and suddenly the same issue occurs, the phones can't connect to it but the tablet can (can't test connection from PC since the adapter is gone). So there's something stopping the phones connecting to a server when it's using the USB Wi-Fi adapter and I don't know what.